# Inserting data to boot sector

Tags: assembly, boot, bootloader, bios, sector

I've got a progra made with my group mate which writes "hello world" on a bootable device (flash drive 4 GB), it's just a little ASM file. On start we select in bios to run from this device, this prints hello world, and then enters normal windows.

But I got a question, is there a chance to edit a boot sector in windows to add this code? It's about 150 code lines (might be less if we cut off comments). If yes - how? We know there is very little place to move in boot sector, but we don't know how to enter it.

Comment: I guess that with Windows you will have hard time as it's nowhere close to open source so I'm not sure if you will be able to edit it anyhow. On the other hand you can do this on Linux, although I won't tell you how (I bet you can find it on the web).

Comment: And maybe without editing, is there a way to put my file as a boot file before windows boot?

Comment: Yes, write your own bootloader that will be loaded by bios, it will do something, and it will load windows bootloader after that. It's like chaining bootloaders. Something like documented in Grub here: http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html

Answer (score 0):

I use [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) for it. Just open the disk and copy your bootloader to the first sector (but bee careful).